# Angular 4 component unit test cannot resolve all parameters (?)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dependency-injection, angular-components

I'm trying to unit test my component but the basic test fails.
`cannot resolve all parameters for MyComponent(?.)`

I tried adding forwardRef() in my component's constructor it works though. But i do not want to use it just because of test failure and it is not recommended.

*please ignore if there are any typo. i've added the code snippet*. sorry that i cannot add the actual code here.

src
    ./services
    **my-service-c.ts**

```
import { MyServiceQ } from './my-service-q';
    ...
    @Injectable()
    export class MyServiceC {
        constructor(private myServiceQ: MyServiceQ) { }
        ...
        getMyServiceQ(){
            return this.myServiceQ;
        }
    }
```

./components
    **my-component.ts**

```
import { MyServiceC } from '../services/my-service-c';
    @Component() {...}
    export class MyComponent {
        private myServiceQ;
        constructor(private myServiceC: MyServiceC) {
            this.myServiceQ = this.myServiceC.getMyServiceQ();
        }
    }
```

**my-component.spec.ts**

```
import { MyServiceC } from '../services/my-service-c';
    import { MockMyServiceC } from '../fixtures/mock-my-service-c';
    import { MyComponent } from './my-component';
    ..other imports...

    beforeEach( () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                { provide: MyServiceC, useClass: MockMyServiceC }
            ],
            declarations: [ MyComponent ]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should be defined', 
        () => expect(component).toBeDefined();
    );
```

Please let me know if you have suggestions. I've been trying to find a solution for a long time.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Before i look at your test, may i ask why are you handling your services that way? Why don't you just inject `serviceQ` directly in your component?

Comment: sorry thats the requirement. I should not expose the serviceQ directly.

Comment: Okay but it's an `Injectable()` it seems, so you have to provide it as well or how is it injected in your `MockMyServiceC` anyway?

Comment: @lexith yep, sorry, deleted; I misread the example. OP, please give a coherent [mcve], the ellipsed sections here don't make much sense.

Comment: @jonrsharpe okay no problem :)

Comment: Can you reproduce it? Seems your `MyServiceC` is undefined. It can be circular dependency You can start with https://plnkr.co/edit/tJNwreq1HmJMlc1nfPYR?p=preview

Comment: @mperle you have to show us your `MockMyServiceC` or otherwise we can't give an exact answer.

Comment: @lexith i've two mock service (MockMyServiceC injects MockMyServiceQ) same as the actual service.

Comment: So there's your error.

Comment: @yurzui i'm trying to reproduce though. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated in your comment that "*i've two mock service (MockMyServiceC injects MockMyServiceQ) same as the actual service.*"

At the moment you inject `MockMyServiceC` in your test all dependencies of `MockMyServiceC` have to be resolved as well, but you didn't provide them.

Changing your test a bit should solve your problem:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
        MockMyServiceQ,
        { provide: MyServiceC, useClass: MockMyServiceC }
    ],
    declarations: [ MyComponent ]
});
```

A hint: 
This can quickly become hard to maintain. Your mocked services should always inject the same, real services. Then you could just provide them like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
        { provide: MyServiceQ, useClass: MockMyServiceQ },
        { provide: MyServiceC, useClass: MockMyServiceC }
    ],
    declarations: [ MyComponent ]
});
```

Otherwise you come to a point where you are injecting MockServices directly as well as provide them via `useClass`. Think about what happens for your test if your component injects MyServiceQ as well.

Comment: i'll try it and let you know the results. Thank you

Comment: i've a question. the above solution will work even if we i had done this in MockMyServiceC
`this.mockMyServiceQ = new MockMyServiceQ();` instead of DI inside constructor params

Comment: Do you mean, if your approach in the question would work if you did this? Probably, if you don't inject it.

Comment: Would have to test it, but i think it should work. It's not injected and no other class would inject it so it doesn't need to be provided. In any other case it's just a normal class.

Comment: it did not work. I tried with both the options in the answer (with and without DI).

Comment: @mperle then i think you have to provide a reproducable plunker